# Create a variable of a specific length and populate it with 0's and 1's

Tags: matlab

I am trying to use MATLAB in order to simulate a communications encoding and decoding mechanism. Hence all of the data will be 0's or 1's.

Initially I created a vector of a specific length and populated with 0's and 1's using

```
source_data = rand(1,8192)<.7;
```

For encoding I need to perform XOR operations multiple times which I was able to do without any issue.

For the decoding operation I need to implement the Gaussian Elimination method to solve the set of equations where I realized this vector representation is not very helpful. I tried to use `strcat` to append multiple 0's and 1's to a variable a using a for loop:

```
for i=1:8192
    if(mod(i,2)==0)
        a = strcat(a,'0');
    else
        a = strcat(a,'1');
    end
    i = i+1;
    disp(i);
end
```

when I tried `length(a)` after this I found that the length was 16384, which is twice 8192. I am not sure where I am going wrong or how best to tackle this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably a few answer/questions here. Firstly, how can one go from an arbitrary vector containing `{0,1}` elements to a string? One way would be to use `cellfun` with the converter `num2str`:

```
dataDbl = rand(1,8192)<.7;                       %see the original question
dataStr = cellfun(@num2str, num2cell(dataDbl));
```

Note that [cellfun](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/techdoc/ref/cellfun.html) concatenates uniform outputs.

Answer (score 2):

Did you reinitialize `a` before the example code? Sounds like you ran it twice without clearing `a` in between, or started with `a` already 8192 long.

Growing an array in a loop like this in Matlab is inefficient. You can usually find a vectorized way to do stuff like this. In your case, to get an 8192-long array of alternating ones and zeros, you can just do this.

```
len = 8192;
a = double(mod(1:len,2) == 0);
```

And logicals might be more suited to your code, so you could skip the `double()` call.